# How to rename multiple files with existing Unix time in file name?

Tags: windows, file, powershell, batch-file

While I know how I would do this in PHP, it doesn't make sense to install IIS, install PHP just to get this done.

I have a folder `D:\Data` that has several subfolders in it. These folders contain files which are backups created with a program that adds a time stamp to the name to allow multiple copies of the file to be backed up.

These files need to be named:

```
usera.dat
```

But they are named currently:

```
usera.dat.17383947323.dat
```

In PHP, I would load the file name into a string, explode the string on ".", then rename the file using the [0] and [3] elements to rename the file, i.e. without the loop to read the directories:

```
$filename = $existing_file
$explodename = explode(".",$filename);
$newfilename = $explodename[0] . "." . $explodename[3];
rename($filename, $newfilename);
```

Does anyone have any recommendation on how to do this with PowerShell or a batch file looping over all the subfolders in `D:\Data`?

Right now I am manually editing each file removing the extra *Unix time stamp.dat* part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner in batch from the prompt:

```
@FOR /r "U:\sourcedir" %a IN (*) DO @FOR %b IN ("%~na") DO @FOR %c IN ("%~nb") DO @IF "%~xc" neq "" ECHO REN "%a" "%~nxc"
```

Note: `echo`es the rename command for testing. Remove the `echo` keyword after testing to execute the rename.

I used `u:\sourcedir` as a test directory.

Translation: for each filename in the subtree (`%%a`) take the name part only and assign to `%%b`, repeat for `%%c` and if there was no extension part in the result, then do the rename.

Comment: Thanks.  This was the easiest to implement and worked amazingly.   Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Translating this from PHP to PowerShell should be a breeze, let's give it a try:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dat.*.dat

foreach($file in $files){
    $filename = $file.Name
    $explodename = $filename.Split('.')
    $newfilename = "$($explodename[0]).$($explodename[3])"
    Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $newfilename
}
```

As shown above:

- PowerShell does not have an `explode()` function, but we can use the `String.Split()` method on any string and get a string array back
- `.` is not a string concat operator in PowerShell, but we can use subexpressions `$(...)` inside an expandable string.
- The `Rename-Item` cmdlet will take care of renaming

---

A more PowerShell-idiomatic solution would be to leverage the pipeline though:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dat.*.dat | Rename-Item -NewName {$explodename = $_.Name.Split('.');"$($explodename[0]).$($explodename[3])"}
```

You could also use a regex pattern in place of the `Split()` method and string concatenation:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dat.*.dat | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^([^\.])\..*\..*\.([^\.])$','$1.$2'}
```

Or do the concatenation with the `-join` operator:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.dat.*.dat | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Split('.')[0,3] -join '.'}
```

Whatever you fancy, `Get-ChildItem` and `Rename-Item` are definitely the commands you'd want to use here

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47857200/45375) contains many helpful pointers, but it seems that the simpler and more robust approach would be to simply drop the *final 2* extensions, assuming that *all* files in the folder tree have these 2 extraneous extensions:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse D:\Data |
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '(\.[^.]*){2}$' }
```